Taking limit in inequality involving Monte Carlo sums
Let $\Omega$ be a domain with size $1$.
Define the Monte Carlo estimator for a continuous function $f$:
$$R_n(f) := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i^n)$$
where $x_1^n, x_2^n, ..., x_n^n$ are iid samples from the uniform distribution in $\Omega$.
Suppose I have $v_n, v \in C^0(\bar\Omega)$ with $v_n \to v$ in $L^2(\Omega)$. Then we know that $R_n(v_n) \to \int_\Omega v$ in $L^2(P)$.
Now I have another sequence $u_n, u \in C^0(\bar\Omega)$ with $u_n \to u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ and also the inequality
$$R_n(u_n) \leq R_n(v_n).$$
I want to conclude that
$$\int_\Omega u \leq \int_\Omega v$$
in a sense. I think the argument is: $R_n(u_n)$ converges to $\int_\Omega u$ in $L^2(P)$ and hence also almost surely if we go to a subsequence. The same is true for $R_n(v_n)$. Then taking the limit we obtain the conclusion. How do I make it rigorous?

I was a bit lazy in my answer, so I just write a comment here. Let $U_n := R_n(u_n)$, $U := \int_\Omega u$, etc. Assume that the differences $U_n - U$ and $V_n - V$ are less than $\varepsilon$ in $L^2$. Then, use the triangle inequality for $L^2$. There are some details to fill in
